# Is there a way to loopback all the audios on the webpage to an audio node?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, web-audio-api

I have tried `$('video,audio')` then create source nodes from these `HTMLMediaElement`s.

If the element is a plain video/audio with src, it no longer outputs audio to any a-out device, and instead it is audible from that `MediaElementSourceNode` only.

and if the element is a video/audio whose `.srcObject` set to an existing RTC MediaStream from remote peer, it outputs audio via speakers etc. but, it is not captured through AudioNode, as it's neither drawing wave-from nor freq spectrum.

<Video /> -> MediaElementSourceNode -> AnalyserNode (drawing spectrum/wave)

how to capture all these elements for audio into subsequent nodes?